# What is the difference between a natural transformation and a 2-morphism?

Tags: category-theory

Is one notion more general than the other? Are they just completely distinct ideas? I know very little category theory, but the intuitive definition often given for natural transformations is that they are morphisms between morphisms, and that seems to be exactly what $2$-morphisms are.

If they are the same idea in some contexts, when if at all is the terminology exchangeable, and when would you use one or the other?

Comment: Natural transformations are the 2-morphisms *in a specific category* (namely the category of small categories). Any 2-category has 2-morphisms, so 2-morphism is the general notion.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. If you make this an answer, I'll mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[2-categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/strict+2-category) are a generalization of categories. They do not only possess objects and morphisms between those objects, they also possess "morphisms between the morphisms", so-called *2-morphisms* (all obeying various axioms, of course). A specific exaple of a 2-category is the [2-category of small categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cat), whose objects are categories, whose morphisms are functors between those categories and whose 2-morphisms are natural transformations between those functors. Thus, 2-morphism is the general notion and natural transformations are a specific example thereof.